# why xocde stl source memory typedef have | symbol?

Tags: c++, stl

In Xcode v1 directory, I think it is the STL source code.
The memory file have this line.

The source code file is :
https://opensource.apple.com/source/libcpp/libcpp-31/include/memory.auto.html

```
typedef Alloc::pointer | value_type* pointer;
```

I have no idea what the | symbol means.

Comment: The code you've included is actually a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is written in a comment, so isn't actual C++ code, but it does describe what is happening. `allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer` will be `typedef`d to `Alloc::pointer` (Where `Alloc` is a template parameter) if it exists, otherwise `value_type*`. It loosely reads as "or".

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea what the `|` symbol means.

In this context, nothing important, since, it's part of a comment:

```
/*
    memory synopsis
    ...
    typedef Alloc::pointer | value_type* pointer;
*/
```

where the author decided to use this symbol for documenting their code.

However, notice that `|` does actually mean something while used in actual code, it's the [Bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_OR_%7C) operator.

Comment: The `|` symbol does actually mean something (outside comments) too.

Comment: Thanks. I miss this big piece of code is actually in the big comment section.